# Is that picture a good simplification/representation of an uncountable set?

Tags: set-theory

I wanna have a good simplification of what an uncountable set M looks like. I know that uncountability cannot be shown by Venn diagrams directly, but we cannot show an infinite set directly either, but still something like „{0, 1, 2, …}“ gives us a (false but) pretty good idea of how this set works. So in that sense: What do you think about my picture. Is there anything grossly misleading?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your picture.  it's hard to draw a picture which illustrates that some function or other does not exist.

Comment: What is the red thing in the picture supposed to be?

Comment: I would venture a guess that the red thing is an element of $M$ that doesn't get paired to any element of $\bf N$.

Comment: In my opinion leaving a single element out of bijection doesn't portray uncountability clearly, as we could squeeze the element into bijection as in Hilbert's Hotel. Maybe using a Cantor-set-like shape would help, as the gaps make it appear as a more concrete set of points while still being uncountable? (I'm not sure how to make it visually apparent that there is no bijection to N despite being fractal.)

Comment: It is not possible to visualize the concept of uncountability. Fortunately, Cantor gave us a method that allows to identify most uncountable sets to actually be uncountable.